# Java GUI blocked by long treatment

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

I'm programming an Abalone game in java and my AI freeze the UI 2-3 sec on each move.

```
public GameState doMove(Move move) {
    Color current = this.game.getTurn();
    if (current == Color.NONE) {
        return GameState.OUTOFTURNS;
    } else if (this.game.over()) {
        System.out.println("Partie terminé");
        return GameState.WON;
    }

    System.out.println("Application du mouvement de " + current);
    this.game.getBoard().apply(move);

    AI ai = AI.getInstance();

    System.out.println("On passe au tour suivant");
    Color next = this.game.getNextTurn();

    System.out.println("On met à jour la board");
    this.window.updateBoard(this.game.getTurn());

    if (next.equals(ai.getColor())) {
        System.out.print("L'IA joue... c'est long...");
        doMove(ai.getBestMove(next));
        System.out.println("fini");
    }

    return GameState.RUNNING;
}
```

What should I use ? Thread, SwinWorker, Callable ?
Here's the complete source code :
https://github.com/melkir/Abalone/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/abalone/controller/GameController.java

Comment: Which one you use will depend on whether you're interested in the result and/or need to update the UI during the process

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer, I want that when a the player move a marble the UI is refresh. Then the IA use the result of getBestMove to move his marble and refresh a second time the board.

Comment: I'd probably recommend a SwingWorker, as it provides a done method letting you know that the process has completed

Comment: Thx MadProgrammer, I never had use SwingWorker. Can you give me an example with my code ? or something like the algorithm

Comment: It's seem's that SwingUtilities.invokeLater resolve my UI block.

Comment: involeLater is not a solution, it simply reschedules a event to be processed on the EDT at some time the future, probably masking the result. You can't "wait" for the processing to complete, as this will block the UI, you need to change your logic to allow it to be more event driven, something happens, then you respond to it

Comment: I have use this code and now it's works
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doMove(ai.getBestMove(next));
        }
    });

Comment: `doMove` is still been executed within the context of the EDT, which will cause the UI to block

Comment: Thx, yes the UI is blocked when the method is executed but now the board is updated when the player apply an move. With the method of SwingWorker do I need to calculate and return the value of getBestMove() and when it's done use get() to recover the value, apply the move and update the board right ? The problem is that I need to use final Object in the done() method and I can't apply this.window.updateBoard()

Comment: Pass a reference of the Window to the SwingWoker. Override the done method and use get to retrieve the value returned by doInBackground and then, via some setter in window, set the value